# JS, отслеживание изменений в DIV

Tags: javascript

Доброго времени суток.

Вопрос такой, нагуглить не удалось.

Есть ли какая-либо возможность отслеживания изменения содержания в тегах? Событие какое, может быть?

Или же остается, как кросбраузерный вариант, при загрузке помещать содержимое элемента в переменную и спустя какое то время постоянно проверять, не изменилось ли оно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно посмотреть в сторону [DOMSubtreeModified](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMSubtreeModified), которое отслеживает структурные изменения потомков элемента.

```js
var testDiv = $('#test');
var counter = 0;

testDiv.bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
  console.log('изменилось');
});

setInterval(function(){
  testDiv.append('<p>text' + (counter++) + '</p>');
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test"></div>
```

Еще есть `DOMNodeInserted`, `DOMNodeRemoved`, `DOMAttrModified` и `DOMCharacterDataModified`

---

Но в IE ниже 9 версии это всё недоступно.